# Excluding header and trailer in datastge for file pattern (read method) files

Tags: datastage

I have a sequential file which is having header and trailer records. I have to load this file in the oracle database but while loading the records, the header and trailer must be excluded.

Also, the File read method is not Specified Files but File patterns. So, I don't have the filter option available to use this command sed '1d;$d'.

Please let me know the alternative.

[image: Input File]

Comment: Can you not just exclude any lines where they begin with XPSMH or XPSMT in a transformer?

Answer (score 0):

Look for patterns within your header and trailer records.
Based on your screenshot i can see first 5 characters for a 
Header - XPSMH
Trailer - XPSMT

Use a transformer - LEFT function to extract 5 characters and check against your header and trailer pattern

Pseudo Code will look like  Left(inpcol,5) <>'XPSMH' or Left(inpcol,5) <>'XPSMT'

Conversely you can also code like

Left(inpcol,5) ='XPSMD'  -- To filter only detail records

Hope this helps